# Sort a patch set or agentset with two conditions in NetLogo

Tags: sorting, netlogo

My patches have `cost` and `gain` attributes, and I would like to sort a list of patches with the minimum `cost` and the maximum `gain`. The `sort-by` function works for sorting on one attribute but how can I sort on both attributes?

Comment: can you be more precise about exactly what you want “minimum cost and the maximum gain” to mean? I can imagine several possible meanings — you might subtract one from the other, or only use the latter to break ties in the former, or...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sort an agentset on many attributes, you can use either [`sort-by`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sort-by) or [`sort-on`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sort-on):

```
patches-own [ cost gain ]

to sort-patches
  ca
  ask patches [
    set cost random 100
    set gain random 100
  ]

  let patches-sorted-by sort-by [
    ([ cost ] of ?1 > [ cost ] of ?2) or
    ([ cost ] of ?1 = [ cost ] of ?2 and [ gain ] of ?1 < [ gain ] of ?2)
  ] patches
  show map [[ list cost gain ] of ? ] patches-sorted-by

  let patches-sorted-on sort-on [ (cost * -1000) + gain ] patches
  show map [[ list cost gain ] of ? ] patches-sorted-on
end
```

Which one you prefer is up to you. Using `sort-on` requires to carefully construct your formula (i.e., the above would not work if you can have gains greater than 1000) but is slightly less verbose.

**Edit: a more general way of sorting on multiple criteria**

OK, this is probably overkill for your situation, but I came up with something a lot more general:

```
to-report sort-by-criteria [ criteria items ]
  ; `criteria` needs to be a task that returns a list of numbers
  report sort-by [
    compare-lists (runresult criteria ?1) (runresult criteria ?2)
  ] items
end

to-report compare-lists [ l1 l2 ]
  report ifelse-value (empty? l1 or empty? l2) [ false ] [
    ifelse-value (first l1 = first l2)
      [ compare-lists but-first l1 but-first l2 ]
      [ first l1 < first l2 ]
  ]
end
```

What you need to pass `sort-by-criteria` is a [`task`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#task) that, given one of the items that you want to sort, will report a list of numbers according to which your items will be sorted.

In your case, you would use it like:

```
let sorted-patches sort-by-criteria (
  task [[ list (-1 * cost) gain ] of ? ]
) patches
```

For two criteria, it's probably not worth using, but if you had a long list of criteria, it would probably be a lot easier and clearer to use than any of the other methods.

Comment: This assumes gain only matters if costs are equal. But I wonder if the poster actually wanted something that always takes both into account.

Comment: It does, yes. I didn't think about that alternative, but I guess that if the poster wanted some sort of weighted ordering of cost and gain, he could use the `sort-on` version and replace `(cost * -1000) + gain` by an appropriate function.

Comment: thank you Nicolas and thank you Seth, in fact I would like to find the best combination between `cost` and `gain`... not only if the cost are equals.

Comment: How do you define "the best combination"? Just `gain - cost`, like Seth suggested above?